# use wireshark to capture all hosts traffic in mininet

Tags: wireshark, mininet

Im trying to capture traffic of all mininet hosts in one wireshark file. For example, I have 3 hosts in mininet, but I dont want 3 different wireshark files (like from xterm), but only one wireshark file, where will be traffic of all 3 hosts captured.

Is it possible in mininet? When I tried:

```
mininet> sh wireshark
```

Only traffic between switches is possible to capture.

Answer (score 1):

Using the above command you can open wireshark. Although, You have to configure wireshark. Which ports do you want to analyze? Please check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR3299ZGk9c)